# Can I put a validation on an Interactive Grid row deletion?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to add a validation on an Interactive Grid, basically to check to see if anything is dependent on the row, so I can display a user friendly error instead of "Ajax call returned server error ORA-20987: APEX - ORA-02292: integrity constraint (FOO.MY_CONSTRAINT)...", but validations always seem to be skipped for deleted rows. Am I doing something wrong? I'm using Apex 5.1.2.

To test, I created a validation on the Interactive Grid, Type = No Rows Returned, SQL Query = SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE :APEX$ROW_STATUS = 'D'. I would expect this would prevent any row from being deleted. Instead, the validation is always skipped. The debug log looks like this:

```
Perform custom validations:
...Validation "New" - Type: NOT_EXISTS
......Skip for row 1 because "Row Status" is "Deleted"
```

I've tried changing the type of the validation, setting Always Execute to Yes, using a scope of either All Submitted Rows and Created and Modified rows, but no luck.

I've created a demo here: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=62159:10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patrick Wolf has confirmed this is a bug and will be fixed. https://community.oracle.com/message/14862207#14862207

Answer (score 3):

You can get a better message for the constraint violation using an [APEX error handling function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71588_01/AEAPI/Example-of-an-Error-Handling-Function.htm#AEAPI2216).  This intercepts the error message and allows you to do whatever you want with it, such as looking for specific constraint names and putting out a more suitable (and clean) message like this:
[image]

Additionally, you could replace the default grid processing by PL/SQL code like this:

```
begin  
     case :APEX$ROW_STATUS  
     when 'C' then
         insert into emp ( empno, ename, deptno )  
         values ( :EMPNO, :ENAME, :DEPTNO )  
         returning rowid into :ROWID;  
     when 'U' then  
         update emp  
            set ename  = :ENAME,  
                deptno = :DEPTNO  
          where rowid  = :ROWID;  
     when 'D' then  
         delete emp  
         where rowid = :ROWID;  
     end case;  
end;
```

Instead of simple DML statements, you could call your own APIs e.g.

```
     when 'D' then  
         emp_pkg.delete_emp (:ROWID);
```

These could then implement your own business rules and error messages before performing the DML.  The error handling function would till be required to remove the "ORA-20001:" and such from the exception messages.

Comment: I'd rather not write my own custom processing if I can avoid it. This page is simple enough that the standard IG processing can handle it. Both these solutions work at the Processing step. Is there no way to catch this at the Validation step?